# Understanding provider attribute "android:multiprocess" in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, multiprocess

In creating a mobile application for Android, I am dealing with a SQLite database which requires a ContentProvider. The ContentProvider is used for adding, update, reading, or deleting data from the database.

I read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html but I did not find any further information what it means, especially for working with databases.

I have seen some manifests that define the following provider:

```
<provider
    android:name="main.ContentProvider"
    android:authorities="main.ContentProvider"
    android:multiprocess="true">
</provider>
```

What does it mean to have multiprocess set to *true*? Does that mean many database queries will be handled simultaneously? And if I set it to *false*, what happens then?

Thx.

Answer (score 4):

An Android framework engineer said "Don't use this attribute"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/u9UMJtALSXw

> Don't use this, it is some old cruft from pre-1.0 design that doesn't
>   work and should be ignored these days.  Just pretend like the
>   attribute doesn't exist. :}
>
> --  You received this message because you are subscribed to the Google Groups "Android Developers" group. To post to this group, send email
>   to android-d...@googlegroups.com To unsubscribe from this group, send
>   email to android-developers+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com For more
>   options, visit this group at
>   http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers?hl=en
>
> --  Dianne Hackborn Android framework engineer hac...@android.com

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `android:multiprocess="true"`.

Not only does it passively not help you, but it even actively causes other problems. For example, if you have `android:multiprocess="true"` then `android:process=":something"` doesn't start in a new process.